# Finding a basis for the set of solutions to a system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to know if my work is correct.

x1=x2+x3-x4

2x1-3x2+x3+x4=0

After row reducing I get :

x1-4x3+2x4=0

x2-3x3+x4=0

Basis is { (4,3,1,0), (-2,-1,0,1) }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to check that the equations are not multiple of each other. Hence the rank is $2$ and the nullity is $2$ as well by rank-nullity theorem.

The solution that you propose are not multiple of each other.

We just have to check that they satisfies the equation.

$$4=3+1-0, 2(4)-3(3)+1+0=0$$

$$-2=-1+0+(-1), 2(-2)-3(-1)+0+1=0$$

The solution is correct.